# How to test the latest Knex migration by rolling back just that migration?

Tags: knex.js

In Knex, every time we create a migration we want to test that migration by rolling forward/back.

However, if we have just rolled forward multiple migrations, there doesn't appear to be any way to test rolling back just *one* migration - *all* of them are rolled back with `migrate:rollback`.

How can we quickly test rolling back migrations one at a time to ensure the DB is in the desired state?  This seems like a very common use case so it seems possible we're overlooking something.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the [only way to do this](https://github.com/tgriesser/knex/issues/666#issuecomment-245054641) is with `knex-migrate`.

Upgrade by a single migration via CLI:

`knex-migrate up`

Roll back a single migration via CLI:

`knex-migrate down`